# c++ aggregates initialization with c-style arrays

Tags: c++, stdarray, stdtuple

In c++14 I have the following type:

```
std::tuple<int[2], int>;
```

How can I properly initialize it? This

```
std::tuple<int[2], int> a {{2,2},3};
```

gives me this error:

> /usr/include/c++/5/tuple:108:25: error: array used as initializer

While this:

```
std::tuple<std::array<int,2>, int> a {{2,2},3};
```

works, but I want to be able to work with standard C-style arrays

Comment: Why do you want raw arrays?  `std::array<int,2>` solves the problem and is a lot easier to work with.  If your worried about speed or efficiency note that `std::array` is a zero cost abstraction and as long as you compile with optimizations on you get the same assembly code.

Comment: `std::tuple` is not aggregate, and `int[2]` is not copyable :-/ ...

Comment: @NathanOliver, I agree with you. I have to work with existing code which uses them though, so I'm trying to see if there are other ways

Answer (score 7):

[`std::tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple) is not an aggregate and doesn't provide a [*list-initializer* constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple). This makes list initialization with that type impossible to use with C-arrays.

You can however use [`std::make_tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/make_tuple):

```
auto a = std::make_tuple<int[2], int>({2,2},3);
```

Comment: or `std::make_tuple<int[2]>({2,2},3);` :). and `make_*` is normally to let compiler deduce type...

Comment: @Jarod42 That's cleverly bizarre. Won't use ;)

Comment: The type turns out to be std::tuple<int*, int>, so we're not there yet unfortunately.